# How would the landscape of a gas giant's core-mantle boundary look like?

Tags: planets, geology, gas-giants

In my setting, the characters live at the bottom of a gas giant's metallic hydrogen ocean, just above the rocky core. There the dense metallic hydrogen acts as the ‘air’ and the core as the ‘ground’ for them, because they have alien ‘biochemistries’ that allow them to live in such condition. Metallic hydrogen is opaque to light, but the characters have some exotic sense that allow them to ‘see’ through it as if it's clear air or water.

The problem is, what kind of sceneries and natural phenomena will they ‘see’? As far as I know, the ‘air’ is magnetically convective, so there will be magnetic ‘winds’. The ‘air’ may also [change phases from superconductor to superfluid vice versa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen#Possibility_of_novel_types_of_quantum_fluid) depending on the magnetic field strength, although I'm not sure if it will produce quantum vortices or not. But how will superconductivity affect things between ‘air’ and ‘ground’, such as the ‘weather’?

Also, apparently [there will be no diamond there](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature.2013.13925), as the carbon gets dissolved in the ‘air’. But I wonder if there could still be ‘rain’ of carbon or other materials near the core's surface (helium-neon rain should be out of question, since it forms thousands kilometers away from the ‘ground’, but is it possible that the rain falls on its surface, since helium and neon are immiscible in hydrogen)?

Comment: There's an old sci-fi story, [Victory Unintentional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victory_Unintentional), with a similar setting. Humans send robots down to the giant's solid core as ambassadors. You might consult it for ideas.

Comment: Rather than inventing an exotic sense, why not use sonar? The speed of sound in metallic hydrogen is likely to be very high, making it an effective long-ranged sense.